# Must the url in a jQuery.post() call be a real url or can it be a relative path?

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

It seems to work as a relative path. Dangerous habit?

```
jQuery.post('/assets/api/addToPicks.php', {imagePath: theImagePath, clientPath: theClientPath});
```

Bob

Comment: Not really - the relative URL will have to be translated into an absolute one anyway when the request is made

Comment: test it and see. I could never get a relative path to work, if oyu can I would love to see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely it can be relative ... there should be no problem

Comment: Thanks. The relative path approach has been working fine for me. I was just worried that I may be "cheating" and would pay the price later in obscure program behavior.